# Filter AJAX search results in WordPress by page template

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search

I am making a WordPress website, which is made up of a Woocommerce Store + Blog section. Both in the Store and on the Blog there is a search engine that shows instant results with AJAX. What I want to do is that, depending on the page where the user is (Blog page or Store page), the search engine will only show results of articles or products, respectively.

After googling and testing, I understood that the conditional tags of Wordpress (is_home (), is_shop (), etc) don't work if they are called from the functions.php file, and the AJAX php function I'm using is effectively inside the functions.php.

The AJAX php function is as follows:

```
<?php 

/**
 * Adding ajax search functionality to the theme
 */
 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_search','ajax_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_search','ajax_search');
 
function ajax_search(){
  global $post;

  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      's' =>$_POST['term'],
      'posts_per_page' =>10
  );    
   
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   
  // display results
  if( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <?php while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
   
    <li>
      <?php 
      $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
      
      foreach ($terms as $term) {
          break;
      } ?>

      <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>

    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

  <?php else: ?>

    <li class="no-results-ajax">No results.</li>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php exit;
}

?>
```

The JQuery function linked with the previous function is as follows:

```
function buscar_ajax(input1, input2) {

    input1.keyup(function(e) {
     
        // prevent browser autocomplete
        jQuery(this).attr('autocomplete','off');
         
        // get search term
        var searchTerm = jQuery(this).val();

        var urlFull  = window.location.href;     // URL completa
        var ruta     = window.location.pathname; // URL sin "http://dominio.com"
        var dominio = urlFull.replace(ruta,''); // URL solo "http://dominio.com"

        if(searchTerm.length > 2) { 
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: dominio + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{
             
            'action':'ajax_search',
            'term' :searchTerm
            },
            success:function(result){    
                input2.fadeIn(200).html(result);
            }
            });
        } else {
            input2.fadeOut(200);
        }

        if(searchTerm.length == 0){
            input2.hide();
        }

        if(e.keyCode == 27){
            jQuery(this).val('');
            input2.hide();
        }

        jQuery('body').click(function(e){
            if ( !jQuery(e.target).hasClass("busqueda") ) {
                input2.fadeOut(200);
                jQuery(this).val('');
            } 
        });
    });

    input1.keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 27){
            jQuery(this).val('');
            input2.fadeOut(200);
        }
    });
}


var buscaHead1 = jQuery('input#s');
var buscaHead2 = jQuery('ul#dhemy-ajax-search');
buscar_ajax( buscaHead1, buscaHead2 );
```

And the HTML code of the search form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="buscador-blog" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input class="busqueda" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Busca en el blog..."/>
    <ul id="dhemy-ajax-search"></ul> <!-- AJAX search -->
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="search-type" value="post" />
  </form>
```

So far, the result is that AJAX shows blog articles or products or articles and products. (changing 'post' to 'product' in the 'post_type' parameter of the $ args array). I need that, if the person is on the Store page, they only show products and if they are on the Blog page, they only show posts.

This could be done if only I had some conditional to evaluate what type of page the user is viewing, and that is where I am trapped.

I very much appreciate any help or guidance you can give me.